# Где захостить телеграм бота на c#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Написал своего бота на с#, теперь нужно его захостить. Какие существуют бесплатные неплохие хосты(нужно чтобы он поддерживал mssql бд и имел хранилище для файлов).

Comment: Для нужд самообразования можно использовать бесплатный тариф https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @LevAri Бесплатные тарифы там прикрывают с удалением аккаунтов :(. Теперь только за бабки.

Comment: Heroku скоро перестанет предоставлять бесплатный тариф.

Comment: Бесплатно только на своем компьютере. И то придется платить за электричество.

Comment: Понятно. Жаль. Тогда бесплатных вариантов похоже не осталось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть много вариантов хостинга, например бесплатные тарифы Heroku или Oracle (оба ушли из России, к сожалению), или вот, например, нашел статью, где автор описывает как захостить бота на Google Cloud Platform:
https://habr.com/ru/post/488560/

Comment: Heroku тоже ушли если что

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение, исправил

Comment: Про гугл я бы тоже уточнил, ибо там не "бесплатно", а "бесплатный пробный" (дают некую сумму, которая тратится, а потом плати), а это не то, что хочет автор как по мне. Ну и судя по комментариям из статьи (`Только есть одно но — Google Cloud не разрешает использовать individual accounts в России, только business.`) - там не все так просто...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ на [Heroku уже нет бесплатных](https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter).

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Прощай эпоха как говорится) А так, это надо автору ответа говорить, а не мне, я лишь сказал, что нынче нельзя с РУ зарегистрировать даже аккаунт там.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ На самом деле, Heroku к происходящему относится с понимание. Зарегаться можно через VPN. Доступ к платформе уже без VPN и никаких блокировок.